# Grails (JUnit) test suite

Tags: testing, grails, junit, spock, test-suite

Do JUnit test suites work in Grails?

I am writing a Groovy/Grails(2.1.2) project using IntelliJ.

Is it possible to run Spock tests as a JUnit test suite?  I have tried:

```
package com.foo

import com.foo.functional.SampleFunctionalSpec
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Suite

@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(Category1.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( {SampleFunctionalSpec.class} )
class SampleTestSuite {
}
```

and

```
package com.foo.functional
import com.foo.*
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;

@Category(Category1.class)
class SampleFunctionalSpec extends BloomGebSpecCase {

    def "Sample test 1 with Category1"() {
        given:
        when:
        println "when"
        then:
        println "Sample test 1 with Category1"
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.foo

interface Category1 { }
```

and I get "Unable to attach test reporter to test framework..." when I run `grails test-app functional SampleTestSuite` from within IntelliJ.

EDIT: Also, just running a test suite with no categories gives same "Unattached" problem:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( SampleFunctionalSpec.class )
class SampleTestSuite { }
```

Comment: How are you running the spec? Who is responsible for the "Unable to ..." message?

Comment: I'm running with IntelliJ

Comment: Edit: this is a groovy/grails project. Does that matter?

Comment: Possibly. First question is if JUnit test suites can be made to work with Grails and plain JUnit. Can you give this a try?

Comment: Good call-- I get the same problem when I try to run a non-Spock JUnit Test Suite using the grails command `grails test-app unit: SimpleUnitTestSuite` So it looks like a grails issue, not a Spock issue.